# Adding columns based on the value from the nearest column

Tags: mysql

I need to kind of normalize a table and specifically add values inside it in a different way.
So, I have this table which looks like this:

```
id | user_id | option1 
1        1         6
```

If this user has another option I need to update the column with a second option and place there the option. This would look like this:

```
   id | user_id | option1 | option2 |
    1      1         6        7
```

But the problem is if there is another user and he also has an option, now the table should look like this:

```
   id | user_id | option1 | option2 |
    1      1         6         7      
    2      2         3
```

The thing is that I need a query that whenever I need to insert an option it checks if the last column has a value and if not place the value there but if it has create another column and place it there, so that way each user would have only one row. What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I would respectfully suggest that your database structure has not been thought through correctly if this is your scenario.  The options should surely appear in their own table that has a FK to the user table?

Comment: The table looks like this because i need to export it's content later in a text file so it's easier to keep the data like this

Comment: I find that a difficult argument to accept; The structure you have adopted is not normalised, and is also the cause of the difficulty you are experiencing now.